# Как разрешить вводить только цифры от 1 до 3 в игре при выборе игрового персонажа?

Tags: python

Пишу игру по, где игрок должен выбрать игрового персонажа (1 - Маг, 2 - Воин, 3 - Разбойник), компьютер отвечает рандомно на атаку игрока, затем у игрока ход защиты.
Проблема с тем, как ограничить выбор для игрока только цифрами 1,2,3. Ввод не ввод букв ограничил с помощью except ValueError и при вводе буквы выдает сообщение и неправильном вводе и игроку повторно предлагается выбрать персонажа, а вот с цифрами так не выходит.
Немного о структуре.
Есть основной файл Game, где непосредственно игровой цикл, файл Models с описанием класса Enemy and Player и атаками/защитами.
Файл Settings с инфой о жизнях и уровнях, и файл Game Exception с исключениями.

file Game

```
import models
import settings
import re

def read_score():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print("*------------Welcome to Game!----------*")
        command = input('Type "start" or "help":')
        if command == 'help':
            print(settings.HELP_INFORMATION)
        elif command == 'start':
            break
        elif command == 'show scores':
            read_score()
        elif command == 'exit':
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        else:
            print('Wrong command!\n'
                  'Try again')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flag_name = True
    while flag_name:
        flag_name = False
        name = input('Please, enter your "name" : ')
        try:
            for i in name:
                if i.isdigit():
                    raise ValueError("The name must not numbers!")
        except Exception:
            print("The name must not numbers!!")
            flag_name = True
    while True:
        print("----------------------------------------")
        print("May the Force be with you!")
        print("----------------------------------------"'\n')
        print("****************************************")


        def main():
            input_player = True
            while input_player:
                input_player = False
                player.attack = int(input('Select Attack to Use: 1 - WIZARD, 2 - WARRIOR, 3 - ROGUE : '))
                try:
                    for i in player.attack:
                        if i.isdigit() is not True:
                            raise ValueError("Возраст должен быть из цифр!")
                        elif i not in range(3):
                            raise ValueError
                except Exception:
                    print('\n'"Ввод должен быть из цифр и в диапазоне от 1 до 3!")

        player = models.Player(settings.PLAYER_LIVES)
        level = settings.LEVEL
        enemy = models.Enemy(level, settings.LEVEL)
        while True:
            try:
                player.attack(enemy.select_attack())
                player.defence(enemy.select_attack())
            except ValueError:
                    print("Incorrect input\n"
                              "Try again!")
            except game_exceptions.EnemyDown:
                player.score += 5
                print("Enemy Down")
                print(f'scores: {settings.SCORE}')
                settings.LEVEL += 1
                lives = settings.LEVEL


name = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]+|[\d]+', r'', name).strip()
```

file Models

```
import settings
from game_exceptions import EnemyDown, GameOver

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, level, lives):
        self.level = level
        self.lives = settings.LEVEL

    @staticmethod
    def select_attack():
        return random.randrange(1, 3)

    def decrease_lives(self):
        if not self.lives == 0:
            self.lives -= 1
        else:
            raise EnemyDown


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, lives=settings.PLAYER_LIVES, allowed_attacks=None):
        self.name = name
        self.lives_player = lives
        self.Score = 0
        self.allowed_attacks = allowed_attacks
        self.level = settings.LEVEL


    @staticmethod
    def fight(attack, defence):
        if attack == defence:
            return 0
        if attack > defence:
            return 1
        if attack < defence:
            return -1

    def attack(self, enemy_obj):
        attack = int(input('Select Attack to Use: 1 - WIZARD, 2 - WARRIOR, 3 - ROGUE : '))
        attack_res = self.fight(attack, enemy_obj)
        if attack_res == 0:
            print(f'It`s a draw!\n Your lives: {decrease_lives}')
            print("--------------------------------------------------------------")
        elif attack_res == 1:
            print(f'You attacked successfully!\n Your lives:{Player.decrease_lives}')
            print("--------------------------------------------------------------")
            self.decrease_lives()
        elif attack_res == -1:
            print(f'You missed!\n Your lives:{Player.decrease_lives}')
            print("--------------------------------------------------------------")
            return False

    def defence(self, enemy_obj):
        defence = int(input('Select Defence to Use: 1 - WIZARD, 2 - WARRIOR, 3 - ROGUE : '))
        defence_res = self.fight(enemy_obj, defence)
        if defence_res == 0:
            print(f'It`s a draw!\nYour lives:{Player.decrease_lives}')
            print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
            return True
        elif defence_res == 1:
            print(f'You defended successfully!\n Your lives:{Player.decrease_lives}')
            print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
            self.decrease_lives()
        if self.lives_player <= 0:
            return False
        elif defence_res == -1:
            print(f'Enemy missed!\n Your lives:{Player.decrease_lives}')
            print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
            return False

    def decrease_lives(self):
        try:
            if not self.lives_player == 0:
                self.lives_player -= 1
        except GameOver:
            print("Game over")
```

file Settings

```
LEVEL = 1



SCORE = 0
def Scores():
    global SCORE
    SCORE += 10
    SCORE.config(text = "Score: " + str(SCORE))
    Show_scores()
def Show_scores():
    global SHOW_SCORES, SCORE
    if SCORE > SHOW_SCORES:
        SHOW_SCORES = SCORE
        SHOW_SCORES.config(text = "Show scores: " + str(SHOW_SCORES))

HELP_INFORMATION = """Ход начинается с игрока"""
```

file Game_Exception

```
    def __init__(self, score, lines=None):
        self.score = score
        with open(r"scores.txt", "w") as file:
            for line in lines:
                file.write(line + '\n')
                print('Game Over')
    

class EnemyDown(Exception):
    pass

class KeyboardInterrupt(Exception):
    pass

class ValueError(Exception):
    pass

class Validate(Exception):
    pass
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Просто добавьте условие `if`
Например:

```
if player.attack not in [1, 2, 3]:
    ...
```

Если вам нужно чтобы атаки не проходили, то сделайте в цикле `while`:

```
while player.attack not in [1, 2, 3]:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял проблематику вопроса, но возможно похожая структура сможет помочь:

```
correct_numbers = [1, 2, 3]
user_number = input("Выбор 1-3: ")
if int(user_number) in correct_numbers:
    print('Подходящее число.')
else:
    print('Не подходит.')
```

В список добавляем все подходящие числа, делаем проверку на любое из них. Если не подходит, то оповещаем.

Если подходит, то можно туда добавить ещё разветвление, что именно происходит в зависимости от числа.

Думаю, с такой задачей Вы бы справились и сами, скорее всего лучшим способом, поэтому уточните проблему, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ваш вариант подходит (1 пробовала подобное), сообщение о неправильно вводе есть, но при этом атака\защита проходят, т.е. выводится результат. Тут возможно нужно использовать исключение(не знаю, какое подойдет в данной ситуации), потому  что хочу чтобы при неправильном выборе было сообщение и предлагалось заново сделать выбор персонажа.